# Having trouble with a simple program in C, any advice?

Tags: c, int

I am attempting to create a scheduler using a simple equation in C.
The goal of the program is to ask a user the amount of time they spend in a week to study/work
(and if it is over 40 hours tell them they are done for the week).

Being as this is a rudimentary task, I expected it to be fairly easy, as I had done something similar in the past with python 3.3, though after much experimenting, I cannot seem to get my program to function correctly.

- My program works with whole integers, but not with decimals. how do I integrate float? Changing d% to f%?

**Solved** * The main problem is that no matter what numbers the users input, a large negative number is always displayed as the final answer. I attempted to use my knowledge of python to solve this problem in C, but so far I am unable to unstand exactly where I am going wrong. *

Any constructive criticism and/or advice would be amazing.

I've added comments to show my though process behind my coding

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("How many hours in a week are you in class?");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    int b;
    printf("How many hours a week are you studying?");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    int c;
    printf("How many hours have you already spent in class and studying this week?");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    int x = (a+b+c);

    if(x >= 40){
        printf("You have spent all the time required for this week.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf ("You have %d hours more to work and study for this week.\n", x);
    }

    //return 0 to end
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT *

It appears that the 'large negative number' error was occurring in that current session of CodeBlocks only.

I Just restarted my computer and reloaded the program, and it seems to work fine. However, I know my code is not perfect and I would still appreciate the input of anyone more experienced than I.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: logical bug, final printf needs to say (40-x)

Comment: @KarthikT That doesn't account for the "large negative number". I see no reason for that in the code.

Comment: For me, there are no large negative numbers. After having fixed the logical bug, the correct result comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf(%d, *int)` is getting new line chars
Try fgets instead of scanf or fflush(STDIN) clearing buffer before calling scanf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `fflush(stdin)` is UB in C (*works* in MSVC). Moreover the newline left in is not a problem here. See the edit in the question: The *universal* solution (restart the computer) solves the problem ;)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about fflush(stdin) until you mentioned it.

Comment: @KingsIndian #include <stdio.h> 
int fflush(FILE *stream); is C standard library

Comment: fflush() is a C stanard function. But passing stdin to fflush() is a undefined behaviour as defined by the C standard. fflush(stdin) is always wrong (MSVC's support is non-standard).